# Windows 8 - IE 10 Metro - How to print or save a webpage

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I'm running Windows 8 Pro. My default browser is Internet Explorer 10 (and hence opens as a Modern Windows 8 app). I want to know how to print or save a webpage. There are no related settings  available in the browser.

The only option is to select "View on Desktop" and the browser interface familiar to IE 9 opens up on the desktop, through which I could access the above said options and additional settings.

I know the Desktop is not going away anytime soon and that its still an important part of Windows. But if Microsoft is pitching for the Modern Windows UI, why would they leave out important options such as print & save from it and force a user to access the "old" Desktop mode for the same? Even Windows 8 RT supports plug-and-play access to Printers & Peripherals. So not being able to Print from a tablet or access the File System is definitely not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Metro IE, have you tried opening up the `Charms` bar, clicking on `Devices` and then choosing your printer?

As far as saving pages go, I think you can share links via the `Share Charm`, but File / Save As has disappeared. Even worse, it seems you cannot even choose the download folder in Metro IE. How do people even come up with such ideas?

FWIW, I think Metro Chrome does have the ability to save pages to disk or SkyDrive etc.

Comment: Thanks!! I think that was it - makes complete sense - clicking Devices on the Charms bar listed OneNote and XPS. If i had a printer installed, I'm sure it would have been listed. This would help print my page. It would also help me save (I generally print to XPS or OneNote to save - never needed the save webpage/complete-webpages option.) So I'll go ahead and accept your the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a while to get used to this Charms bar thing, but I must admit having per-app settings being so easily accessible is fantastic compared to something like iOS.

Comment: Yes its just amazing - it makes it so simple. Agree it takes a while to get used to few changes - probably that's the reason for some of those steep-learning-curve reviews. If they had truly experienced it, i'm sure the reviews would've be totally different.

Comment: Yup, plenty of people commenting negatively when they hadn't even tried it. Anyway, that's a different discussion altogether...

Answer (score 1):

when I open the devices charm, I see all the options, and the printer is working fine. however, the options to send the webpage to onenote or to nitro pdf creator, even though they show, they are not working, I get a message sayiig "there was a problem connecting to the printer. Make sure it is connected and try again". any ideas/solutions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the Modern UI IE 10 doesn't allow saving pages in the usual way. You can however save the page as PDF if you have Microsoft OneNote installed.

1. Bring up the Devices charm using <kbd>Win+K</kbd>
2. Finally choose Send To One Note to save the page in PDF format
   [image]
3. If you have a printer attached it'll show up in the Devices charm. Select it to print the webpage.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I have already provided the alternative. If not a solution, I was looking for an explanation of why such a design decision was made.

Comment: Saving no, printing yes.

Comment: @Karan You are correct. Thanks. Answer edited.

Comment: Did you just completely change your answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

As to print webpages, I'd just like to add that the easiest way in IE metro style is to press Ctrl+P which brings you directly to the printing charm.

Answer (score 0):

[CTRL + S] when internet explorer 10 on desktop

Comment: question is related to metro ,not a desktop mode